# Can we capture voice input from amazon connect directly and passes to lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

Can we capture voice input from amazon connect(without using any other speech to text API) directly and passes to lambda function?

Comment: Could you be more specific ? I think that this is impossible but I need to understand your need.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Lex at a minimum.

Use a "Get Customer Input" step within Amazon Connect to call a Lex Bot.  Within the Lex Bot configuration, you can pass utterances to Lambda via the "Lambda initialization and validation" setting to validate the spoken utterance or use the "Fulfillment" setting to apply business logic to the spoken utterance.